# What happiness/joy God gets, when we humans pray him?

Tags: gods

According to Hinduism , What happiness or joy Gods gets when we humans pray ?

Does God really feel happy when his devotees pray? What joy God gets when some one pray or when humans see temple/god photo they do namaskara.

Does God get joy from this act?

Not duplicate of Why should we pray/worship God? : because wanted answer from gods point of view , what god gets not what uses for the worshiper.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should we pray/worship God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3917/why-should-we-pray-worship-god)

Comment: @iammilind i want answer from god points of view ..

Comment: What do you mean by God? Deva or Brahman?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Deva: TheCreator of all

Comment: @AmruthA Brahman or ParaBrahma is creator of all. Devas are Gods and lower forms of Parabrahma.

Comment: the so-called "gods" exist only in prayer.  if nobody prays to a god, he ceases to exist.

Comment: God himself is Sat-Chit-  Ananda   ,he himself is bliss. We realise this bliss  when we pray to him.

Comment: what happiness/joy do your parents get if you obey them ? what happiness/joy do you get if your son/daughter obeys you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, certainly is that the Lord becomes satisfied and feels some joy when his devotee is doing something with devotion and affection (bhakti) for the Lord.
Lord Krishna says in the [Bhagavad gita 7.17](https://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/7/17):

> teṣāṁ jñānī nitya-yukta
>   eka-bhaktir viśiṣyate
>   priyo hi jñānino ’tyartham
>   ahaṁ sa ca mama priyaḥ
>
> Of these, the one who is in full knowledge and who is always engaged in pure devotional service (bhakti) is the best. For I am very dear to him, and **he is dear to Me**.

In the verse words *sa ca mama priyaḥ* "he is dear to Me" indicate that the Lord feels joy and satisfaction when we do some devotional activity.

Answer (score 2):

Well let me ask you another question: Why do humans pray to God? Do you think that we humans pray only when we are happy? It's the other way around, we humans only pray when we are sad, depressed, not able to get what we desire and so on.

> Dukh mein sumiran sab kare, sukh mein kare na koye Jo sukh mein
>   sumiran kare, to dukh kahe ko hoye
>
> दुख में सुमिरन सब करे, सुख में करे
>   ना कोय | जो सुख में सुमिरन करे, तो दुख कहे को होय ||
>
> In anguish
>   everyone prays to Him, in joy does none To one who prays in happiness,
>   how can sorrow come

As parents (or our parents) we all do so much for our kids but never expect them to pray us, if they show love, care we feel happy but if they don't we never feel sad, we keep on doing what we think is good/beneficial for them, right? Similarly when we bow before the almighty we show our gratitude for there are so many others who are not as privileged as us. So it is not he who is seeking happiness in what we do, it's us. Ask yourself what can you give him who has given you everything?

Even Lord Rama in human form worshiped Shiva to seek his blessings/assistance when he was in crisis. Read [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10945/did-lord-rama-really-worship-lord-shiva)

Answer (score 2):

Phalam,pushpam, thoyam.. God is happy with the smallest expression of love or Bhakti. In all religions it is given that humble attention/offerings from the one who offers prayer is sufficient sustenance of a higher spirit. Why are temples constructed? Why light a small lamp? If it is believed that it is just faith or mere belief/assumption (of the existence or fondness) from devotees' attention towards God, then how come it exists for so many centuries and in so many faiths?

Even if it is argued that higher God is made by man, then man must be happy due to action from a regulatory self-attention / self-realization mechanism.

SaiBaba expected such attachment is necessary for a loving protective function. Jesus Christ asked Simon why he lost his earlier trust after making a beginning.When resumed was rewaeded with boat overflowing catch.

Seen with the duality identity in Advaitha *an internal part* of the person praying is deeply satisfied and it sets him more powerfully along the Dharmic path.