Why do gods have emotions?
I surprise why gods have emotions.
We say that when we worship, then god will be pleased and gives boons. Why god will be happy (which is an emotion) when we chant a mantra?
If god has emotions then many questions will arise like below?

If I worship today and wont worship tomorrow so he will be angry?

Will he create problems to worship him?

He may delay the boons to worship him for more time.

He might be watching me and laughing at me to see how I am worshipping him.


Many such silly questions will arise when god has emotions.
Any god you see in our religion Lord Shiva, Vishnu, Ganesha, Durga, Rama, Krishna, Venkateshwara has some emotion.
Why is it like that?
Dont say that god will never be angry on devotees and he is a good person, even having mercy on people also is an emotion.

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22887/what-happiness-joy-god-gets-when-we-humans-pray-him
