# What reasoning does Chinna Jeeyar offer when he says Rama never worshiped Shiva in Ramayana?

Tags: shiva, rama, vaishnavism, worship

Here's what Chinna Jeeyar [says](https://chinnajeeyar.guru/chinnajeeyar/faq-items/humble-salutations-to-hh-jeeyar-swamiji-i-shall-be-gretful-to-you-if-you-could-clear-my-doubt-in-the-valmiki-ramayana-sri-rama-is-said-to-have-worshipped-lord-shiva-at-rameshwaram-in-the-mahabarat/):

> **Sri Rama never worshiped Lord Shiva, according to Sri Ramayanam**. He did not consecrate Rameswaram. This is a made up story. Anything related to Sri Rama, will be accepted if Valmiki Ramayana mentions that.

Our own Tezz has given [a citation](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18507/5212) - not even using the Rameshwaram reference:

> वैश्वदेवबलिम् कृत्वा **रौद्रम् वैष्णवमेव च** | 
>  वास्तुसंशमनीयानि मङ्गळानि प्रवर्तयन् || २-५६-३१ 
>  जपम् च न्यायतः कृत्वा स्नात्वा नद्याम् यथाविधि | 
>  पाप संशमनम् रामः चकार बलिम् उत्तमम् || २-५६-३२
>
> Having taken bath in the river as prescribed Rama offered oblations to **Lord Rudra (Shiva)** and **Lord Vishnu** after offering tributes to Vaisvadeva. He performed benedictions relating to the purification of house and also a silent prayer as per prescribed rites. He finally offered excellent tributes to the deities, for removing sins.

So why does Jeeyar think Rama never worshiped Shiva (according to Valmiki Ramayana)? Does he offer any reasoning in support of his stated views?

Comment: Offering oblations is different from worship. The shloka above says that Rama offered oblations to Vaishwadeva, Rudra and Shiva. Many brahmanas also offer oblations to Soma, Varuna etc as part of daily rites. They are not considered as worshipping Soma, Varuna, Agni etc.

Comment: Definition of oblation
1 : the act of making a religious offering; specifically,  capitalized : the act of offering the eucharistic elements to God
2 : something offered in worship or devotion : a holy gift offered usually at an altar or shrine

Comment: Oblation is an English approximate translation. There’s no use of consulting an English dictionary for this particular rite.

Comment: @user1952500 its not true .. oblation is indeed worship.. i guess u havent done these rituals !!

Comment: Chinna Jeeyar Swamy is a Vaishnava and Vaishnava like to see their Ishta i.e. Vishnu as supreme. So naturally, they would say Vishnu doesn't worship Shiva. Nothing's wrong with such beliefs.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury That is utterly wrong. Where did you get the idea that it is a belief that  a devotee would like to see their own God as supreme? They only say where are facts and references. And also remember that you are talking about a Jeeyar not a normal devotee or a person. A Jeeyar doesn't spill rumours. They said because Mahadeva there is Varuna, the sea God.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I never said devotees don't give facts. And Jeeyars are enlightened indeed. Nobody is spreading rumours.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury What do you mean by this "Chinna Jeeyar Swamy is a Vaishnava and Vaishnava like to see their Ishta i.e. Vishnu as supreme." ? By this statement, it means that you are considering Chinna Jeeyar swami normal devotee and they like to see their ishta as supreme. But the words were not said due to that. It is said like that because there Rama is talking about Varuna. Those who reads and understand whole sarga 89 will understand it.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I didn't mean Chinna Jeeyar Swami to be a normal devotee.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.templepurohit.com/forums/topic/which-hindu-scriptures-refer-to-rama-and-krishna-worshiping-shivalinga/

vaishnavites have argued that "mahadeva" in the following verse is not Siva but the Ocean:

"In Verse 19 of Yuddha Kanda – Book Of War, Chapter [Sarga] 123, Valmiki Ramayana, Lord Rama himself says that he worshiped Mahadeva.

एतत् कुक्षौ समुद्रस्य स्कन्धावारनिवेशनम् || ६-१२३-१९
अत्र पूर्वं महादेवः प्रसादमकरोत्प्रभुः |

“See this island, located in the middle of the ocean, where my troops were stationed. At this place, the lord Shiva (the supreme deity) formerly bestowed his grace on me.”"

It doesn't make sense that Rama would worship the ocean since he had threatened to dry up the ocean using a brahmastra.

this is also confirmed by brahmanda purana:

"Actually the above verse of Valmiki Ramayana is describing this event which is described in Yuddha Kanda of Adhyatma Ramayana of Brahmanda Purana:

सेतुमारभमाणस्तु तत्र रामेश्वरं शिवम् ।
संस्थाप्य पूजयित्वाह रामो लोकहिताय च ॥ १॥
प्रणमेत्सेतुबन्धं यो दृष्ट्वा रामेश्वरं शिवम् ।
ब्रह्महत्यादिपापेभ्यो मुच्यते मदनुग्रहात् ॥ २॥
सेतुबन्धे नरः स्नात्वा दृष्ट्वा रामेश्वरं हरम् ।
सङ्कल्पनियतो भूत्वा गत्वा वाराणसीं नरः ॥ ३॥
आनीय गङ्गासलिलं रामेशमभिषिच्य च ।
समुद्रे क्षिप्ततद्भारो ब्रह्म प्राप्नोत्यसंशयम् ॥ ४॥

During the construction of bridge, Rama installed Mahadev and worshipped him calling by the name Rameshwar Mahadev. He described his glory, “If someone visits the bridge (setubandh), and prostrates to Rameshwar mahadev he is liberated of the severest of sin of killing Brahmins.” Rama stated, “One should bathe here in sea, and having darshan of Rameshwar Mahadev, he should go to kashi, to fetch ganga water. Offering the Ganga water of Kashi over Rameshwar Mahadev, he should throw the pot in sea. Thus, he is bound to get salvation.”