# What is the basis to say Rama didn't worship Shiva when his mother clearly did?

Tags: shiva, ramayana, rama

From [Ayodhya Kanda - Book Of Ayodhya Chapter [Sarga] 25](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/ayodhya/sarga25/ayodhya_25_frame.htm):

> smR^itir dhR^itiH ca dharmaH ca paantu tvaam putra sarvataH |
>   skandaH ca bhagavaan devaH somaH ca sabR^ihaspatiH || 2-25-11
>   sapta R^iSayo naaradaH ca te tvaam rakSantu sarvataH |
>
> "May Veda, the Smriti texts taken as one body, the resolution and the piety protect you, my son! May lord Skanda (the younger son of Lord Siva)and the moon god along with the sage Brihaspati(the preceptor of gods), the well known seven sages as well as Sage Narada guard you on all sides."
>
> sarva loka prabhur brahmaa bhuuta bhartaa tathaa R^iSayaH || 2-25-25
>   ye ca sheSaaH suraaH te tvaam rakSantu vana vaasinam |
>
> "Let Siva, the lord of all spheres, Brahma, the lord of creation, Vishnu, the nourisher of beings, the sages and the rest of the celestials may protect you dwelling in the forest."
>
> mayaa arcitaa deva gaNaaH shiva aadayo |
>   maharSayo bhuuta mahaa asura uragaaH |
>   abhiprayaatasya vanam ciraaya te|
>   hitaani kaankSantu dishaH ca raaghava || 2-25-45
>
> "Oh, Rama! Worshipped by me, let the hosts of gods headed by Siva, the Supreme Being, the great sages, spirits, the chief of evil spirits, the celestial serpents and the (four)quarters wish well of you, who is setting forth to forest, "

Here we can see that his mother clearly worshipped Shiva. What is the basis to say Rama didn't worship Shiva?

Comment: She gives names of all the deities, seasons, quarters, guardians of the quarters, serpents. Yama etc.,  etc., . Not only Shiva alone. That is like a blessing. She worshipped all of them . In preceding verses, she performed oblations to the said Gods. So did Rama when he worshipped Vaishvedevas, Brahma, Vishnu as a part of yajna only. It is said in Aranya Kanda. Not as a supreme being or by consecrating Shiva Lingas.  "Why wouldn't Rama worship..." this may lead to opinion based answers.

Comment: @SK lord rama worshiped lord shiva at rameshwaram and in yuddha khand of valmiki ramayana he says that he worshiped lord shiva and ofcource both are one. And it seems it is just a well being prayer as when a man set off to a journey it is said "may god protect you" and other gods are too invoked.

Comment: I understand.  but when a major religious figure says the basis of the magnificent Rameshwaram temple is a "made up story" - it is shocking.  @fierce lord by the way kausalya clearly says she worships Siva

Comment: @SK you should go here:— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10945/did-lord-rama-really-worship-lord-shiva and i did not understand your first paragraph in comment what you said please clarify it. Yes lord shiva is worshiped by kaushalya ji but sages and other beings are too invoked.

Comment: Again, question is not clear enough, "What is the basis to say Rama didn't worship Siva..." - who made the claim?

Comment: please see the chinna jeeyar quote above @sv.

Comment: I edited your other question and marked for reopening so there's no need of multiple Q's on the same topic. You should try to ask objective Q's instead of making statements / pointing out contradictions and asking for people's opinions.

Comment: as you can see they are trying to close the question.  but I have figured out how to ask most of my questions unmolested.  let them do what they want to do - cream will rise to the top @sv.

Comment: It's me who voted this one for closure! Because I thought [the other one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24258) was a good candidate for re-opening after some edits. "but I have figured out how to ask most of my questions unmolested" - I didn't think so. Look at this one, you have a question in the title but no explanation whatsoever in the body. Nobody has time to put themselves in your shoes and understand where you're coming from. The question has to be complete in all respects.

Comment: What's this fuss about Rama worshipping Lord Shiva? Obviously he did..according to Vashishta Krutha shiva Daridra Dahana Stotram, Rama is is a devotee of Shiva.. so he must have done Nitya Puja of Shiva..Rama also worshipped Goddess Durga (Akala Bodhan) plus he is also said to have worshipped Supreme Goddess Lalitamaba as per Brahmanda Purana..@SK So, what's so bizarre in it? Even Krishna worshipped Lord Shiva (Devi Bhagavatam) worshipped Tripuramaba..

Comment: rickross Yes, valmiki ramayana did not mention it clearly @SK but says :— 

**"See this island, located in the
middle of the ocean, where my
troops were stationed. At this
place, the lord Shiva (the
supreme deity) formerly
bestowed his grace on me."**

**—Quote taken from Valmiki
Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Sarga
123, Verse 19**

This quote is taken from answer given here(it's not my finding)— https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10945/did-lord-rama-really-worship-lord-shiva

Comment: @SK: good question