# What should I [strictly] do to follow Hinduism as a way of life?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, dharma, culture, sects

If I decide to follow Hinduism as a way of life, what exactly would I have to do, strictly according to the Vedanta philosophy?

I want to know what ancient Hindu scriptures say regarding this, not the personal preference/opinion of anyone who answers this question.

What I mean is, is there a certain set of rules I should follow (e.g., abstaining from meat, practising Yoga, meditation, etc.)?
Also, could someone suggest some books/scriptures I can read to get a better idea about what the "Vedic way of life" actually is?
Let me make it clear that I am NOT referring to Hinduism as a *religion*, but as a *way of life*, so I don't expect answers like worship a particular deity (e.g., Shiva), or perform a particular ritual (e.g., some xyz Puja).

PS: I have already started reading a reputed translation of the Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: The following [link](http://hinduwebsite.com/hinduwaycorrect.asp) will be helpful

Comment: Your Question is broad. Just search all your doubts and all your queries are already answered on this site. [Should a Brahmin be vegetarian?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8206/3500), [Why one should worship God?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2948/3500). Yoga and Meditation are again vast subjects. Just see @jabahar (Be Happy) Answers. They give you good insight on Sanatana Dharma and Spirituality. Study some concepts of Karma, Yoga, Schools of Hinduism. Then you will understand what exactly is Sanatana Dharma.

Comment: Also, check out [What is the ultimate goal of Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/4148/2995) and [How to introduce Hinduism to Children?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/how-to-introduce-hinduism-to-children)

Comment: I have 2 questions to have a better understanding of your question -Are you not a HIndu?Or are you newly converted to Hinduism?

Comment: You should read vedanta  philosophies (all 3 philosophies advaita/vishisthadvaita/dwaita) , and all commentries on Bramha Sutras, and then decide your world view. Which can be supported by Shastras like itihas,shrimad Bhagwad gita etc. This would make you as close as it can get to real vedic ideology and way of thinking/ beliefs . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta

Comment: Following a vedic way of life means primarily 1. satyam vada- speak the truth 2. dharmam chara - walk the path of dharma. Since you are a girl, and looking to understand the dharmic way of life, read up the stories of ideal women in scripture and emulate them as much as possible. Like Sita. Your last name indicates that you are born into a brahmin family. So, vegetarianism, soucham (cleanliness of body, environment,  & mind and food) are to be practised. Rever the vedas and those who study the vedas. Worship your parents and teachers. This should be a good start.

Comment: Suggest reading "The Spiritual Heritage of India" by Swami Prabhavananda. It will give you an overview of what the different scriptures are and how they are related, what the different philosophies are, what the different sects are, what the different ethical and moral principles are that are shared by all, etc., etc.

Comment: @AnilKumar The reason my question is broad is that I don't have the first idea about where to start and am rather overwhelmed with all the resources there are. But thanks for giving me a starting point! I'll browse the questions that have been asked on this SE till now to get a better idea of what I should do, or at least in order to come up with more specific questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Swami Vivekananda,the main teaching of Vedanta is--"Every soul is potentially Divine".The role of the individual is to *unravel the Divinity within*.
The Bhagawad Gita states that the *soul is eternal and indestructible*.The philosophy--"Aham Brahmasmi" --I and my Father are one --Atma and Paramatma are One--comes from his belief.
 Fist part of a man's struggle is to convince himself of this truth.
Second part of a man's struggle is overcome all fears .Is is only then ,that a man can assert his inherent Divinity.
The life of Swami Vivekananda , is an example of what one should do next.You do not have to copy Vivekananda. You have to live your own life in your own way.*Do what you think to be the best*.

Answer (score 1):

Gita is considered a parallel philosophy of VedAnta & Hinduism well recognizes it. If you think that Hinduism is just another name of *"SanAtana Dharma"*, then **we all already are following it; nothing has to be changed to integrate Hinduism as a way of life**.

> BG 4.11 - The way they approach Me, exactly in same way I serve them; O Partha, **all human beings follow My path in every way**.
>   BG 9.29 - I am impartial towards all beings; to Me there is none detastable or none dear. But those who worship Me with devotion, they exist in Me, and I too exist in them.

Now if you think that Hinduism is a collection of various sectarian philosophies, then you may choose any sect of your choice OR have your own sect/God OR even be atheist -- all options are again way of life. **All you do, will be certain way of life, hence part of Hinduism**.

In short, Hinduism has nothing to do with what we adopt as our way of life, because it's synonymous to "way of life".

Answer (score 1):

Hinduism leaves it up to you to do as you think fit.

> '...Reflecting on this entire teaching do as you think fit.'

Gita 18.63

The only rule that is there in Hinduism is that there is no rule.

Answer (score 0):

The Bhagvat Gita is not an independent scripture. It is part of Mahabharata. Only reading Bhagvat Gita is not ideal. Mahabharata is ideal scripture for you, read Vedas and other Puranas only if you wish to be an expert on the subject. Because Mahabharata is written for the people of Kali Yuga ie, you.

Also see if you can find a no bullshit guru, who is a scholar and a sanyass. Because there are many wrong interpretations of Bhagvat Gita. I think Swamy Chinmayananda(RIP, his talks are on youtube) is a great guru. I also like one of his disciple Swamy Sandeep Chaithanya who I get all my knowledge about Mahabharata from, but his talks are in Malayalam. These gurus are genuine in my opinion.

You can also check out http://www.schoolofbhagavadgita.org/ I don't know if all their publications are in Malayalam or not. You have to enquire. But still a good source on Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas.

Also you can check out one of my favorite philosophers on Hinduism and Buddhism, Alan Watts(RIP) on youtube. Jiddu Krishnamurthy(RIP) is also worth mentioning. Great talks by all these people are available on youtube I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a question like "What should I study to get a job in India?"

As ages have gone past Avatar Purusha's live presence on Earth, we have to upgrade our knowledge in Hinduism to greater heights.

Following are needed in theory & practice to be a Hindu (Sanaatani)

Subjects:
HARIPRIYA: Food ethics,
MOHANAM: Men-Women behaviour,
NAGARI: Interelations,
NYAASA: Knowledge on Karma & Yoga
VARNAM: One's occupational obedience, AASHRAMA: Mantraas, Taantrika proyoga (tricks to survive),
AATMA RAHASYA: Secrets of souls,
BHAKTHI: ways of devotion to teacher & God,
PAAPANAASHAM: Rectifying oneself / washing away sins.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).